# Piping log output through a C program for easy log rotation

Tags: c, bash, logrotate

I'm trying to make it really easy to logrotate some of my apps that log via bash redirection. Basically, I have a C program that reads STDIN into a buffer. It reads this buffer, and whenever it encounters a newline, it will write the output it has gathered to a file.

The difference in this program is that it does not leave the file open. It opens it for appending *each time a new line is encountered*. This works *great* with the logrotate utility, but I'm wondering if there's some sort of horrible unforseen issue I'm not accounting for that I'll run into later on.

Is it better just to implement signal handling in this utility and have logrotate send it a SIGHUP? Are there horrible performance penalties to what I'm doing?

So normally where you'd do:

```
./app >> output.log
```

With the logger util you do:

```
./app | ./mylogger output.log
```

Although I'm too bad in C, I'm not very well versed in its best practices. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the source:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define MAX_WRITE_FAILS 3

/**
 * outputs the given content to the specified file.
 */
int file_output(char *filename, char *content, size_t content_length)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp  =   fopen(filename, "a");
    content[content_length + 1] =   '\0';
    if(fp == NULL) return errno;
    fwrite(content, sizeof(char), content_length, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Loops over STDIN and whenever it finds a newline, sends the current content
 * buffer to the file specified on the command line.
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    char *content           =   malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFSIZE);
    size_t content_size     =   0;
    int content_buf_size    =   BUFSIZE;
    int write_failures      =   0;
    char *file;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: logger <file>");
        exit(1);
    }
    file    =   argv[1];

    // loop over STDIN
    while(fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, stdin))
    {
        int output_err;
        int buflength   =   strlen(buffer);

        // loop over character for character, searching for newlines and
        // appending our buffer to the output content as we go along
        for(i = 0; i < buflength; i++)
        {
            char *old   =   content;

            // check if we have a newline or end of string
            if(buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\0' || (i != (buflength - 1) && buffer[i] == '\r' && buffer[i+1] == '\n'))
            {
                content[content_size]   =   '\n';
                output_err  =   file_output(file, content, content_size + 1);
                if(output_err == 0)
                {
                    // success! reset the content size (ie more or less resets
                    // the output content string)
                    content_size    =   0;
                    write_failures  =   0;
                }
                else
                {
                    // write failed, try to keep going. this will preserve our
                    // newline so that the next newline we encounter will write
                    // both lines (this AND and the next).
                    content_size++;
                    write_failures++;
                }
            }

            if(write_failures >= MAX_WRITE_FAILS)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write output to file %d times (errno: %d). Quitting.\n", write_failures, output_err);
                exit(3);
            }

            if(buffer[i] != '\n' && buffer[i] != '\r' && buffer[i] != '\0')
            {
                // copy buffer into content (if it's not a newline/null)
                content[content_size]   =   buffer[i];
                content_size++;
            }

            // check if we're pushing the limits of our content buffer
            if(content_size >= content_buf_size - 1)
            {
                // we need to up the size of our output buffer
                content_buf_size    +=  BUFSIZE;
                content =   (char *)realloc(content, sizeof(char) * content_buf_size);
                if(content == NULL)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to reallocate buffer memory.\n");
                    free(old);
                    exit(2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered just using copytruncate for logrotate instead of reinventing `tee`?

Comment: No, because I haven't heard of either. Thanks, I'll check both out!

Comment: Funny, `copytruncate` does exactly what I needed all along. Thanks.

Comment: We use `logrotate` at work with long running daemons and we just configure `logrotate` to emit a signal (`SIGHUP` or `SIGUSR1`) and the logging processes to close and reopen the file only when such signal is received.  I can't find any justification to closing and opening a file on every output line, but if you are going to buffer yourself anyway, why use `fopen()` instead of `open()`?

Comment: Keep in mind that copying the log before truncating might take a while and all those logs in between the two operations will be lost - as explained in the man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since my suggestion in the comments turned out to be what you needed, I am adding it as an answer, with more of an explanation.

When you have a logging application which can not be told to close its logfile (usually via SIGHUP), you can use the 'copytruncate' option in your logrotate.conf.

Here is the description from the man page:

> ```
>   Truncate  the  original log file in place after creating a copy,
>   instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new
>   one,  It  can be used when some program can not be told to close
>   its logfile and thus might continue writing (appending)  to  the
>   previous log file forever.  Note that there is a very small time
>   slice between copying the file and truncating it, so  some  log-
>   ging  data  might be lost.  When this option is used, the create
>   option will have no effect, as the old log file stays in  place.
> ```

Source: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html